# How to copy list of values from one array to another array on some interval using Rxjs?

Tags: rxjs5

Using Rxjs, I need to copy 10 next values evey 200ms from arr1 to arr2. I come up with below code, but there should be some Rxjs way to do.

```
originalArr= [];

newArr = [];

Rx.Observable.interval(200)
        .scan((acc, val) => acc + 10)
        .takeWhile(v => v < this.value.length)
        .subscribe(val => {
            const arr = this.value.slice(val, val+10);
            arr.forEach(v => this.newVal.push(v));
        });
```